# Problems with the encoding in the file name with send_data (ruby-on-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, character-encoding, ubuntu-16.04, filenames

I have a server:
ubuntu 16.04
nginix
passenger

I try to send the file using the means of send_data, the file name is Cyrillic, but when I receive (as a result of downloading the file), the file name is obtained in the wrong encoding.
Example:
On server: Сводный_отчет_по_СПК_имени_Куйбышева_за_25.04.2019г.xlsx
Upon downloading: Ð¡Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ñ_Ð¹_Ð¾Ñ_Ñ_ÐµÑ__Ð¿Ð¾_Ð¡Ð_Ð_ Ð_Ð¾Ð»Ñ_Ð¾Ð· Ð¸Ð¼. Ð_ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ð½Ð°_Ð·Ð°_25.04.2019Ð³.xlsx

my function

```
send_data package.to_stream.read, type: 'application/xlsx', filename: "Сводный_отчет_по_#{name}_за_#{to_date}.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the encoding

```
type: 'application/xlsx; charset=utf-8;
```

Comment: This option will make the content of the document encoded in utf-8, in our case it works, but the FILE NAME will still be in the form of hieroglyphs (